# UITableView cell icon and label are misplaced

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using default UITableViewCell and just set icon, label, detailLabel but for some reason with specific text length my icon jumps to the left top corner.
The issue is resolved after switching tab to another one and back.

Here is how it looks:

[image: Misplaced icon and text]

How it should look like:

[image: Correct]

It's related to text size and word-wrapping somehow because when I add or remove at least symbol - it works fine.

P.S. I've tried to tableView.reloadData on viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear etc and it doesn't help unfortunately.
UITableViewCell is default, no custom xib / storyboard.

Any ideas what's going on here?
Thanks!

Comment: are you usin Autolayout ?

Comment: just regular UITableView cell, I didn't add any constraints there. (I guess it uses auto layout but I'm not sure)

Comment: you have to give constraints to your icon and label then It will be as your desired output

Comment: hm, icon and label are not mine, they're part of the cell, I didn't add them. I'm curious - should we add constraints to default table view cells?

Comment: Try setting the cells content view translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints to false

Comment: @OverD thanks, just tried that - didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, You can add constraint to your default tableviewcell. Constraints are now mostly used and you can fixed your object in screen where you want

Comment: @JitendraModi I guess for that I need to create my custom cell? Or just add constraints to existing controls? (creating custom cell would be too much effort for this defect)

Comment: are you working with xib or using storyboard ? If you are using xib then take a custom cell and give constraint in it. If you use storyboard then you can take a prototype cell or can take a csutom cell but you have to give constraints

Comment: @JitendraModi I don't use xib and storyboard for my cell because my cell is not custom, but for other views (as well as parent view for tableview) I'm using storyboard.

Comment: What cell type are u using?

Comment: @AlexanderStepanov where did you place the code?

Comment: @Tj3n I'm using default UITableViewCell

Comment: @OverD the code is inside func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
            willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, 
               forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)

Comment: @AlexanderStepanov I think I have figured it out, change the text label number of lines to 2. In theory should fix you issue

Comment: @OverD thanks for suggestion! just tried that and result is the same unfortunately..

Comment: I pretty sure it has something to do with content hugging....due to the length of the text....can you try changing the width of he text labels frame and check what effect this has.

Comment: @OverD I've just tried that, like .sizeToFit, still no result. But I got is solved. I was adding some content to .contentView like left green vertical line, I changed it to add subview to cell directly and problem got solved. Weird. Let me add the answer for question with details. Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved finally.

I was adding left green line like that:

```
let cellHeight = self.estimatedHeight(todo: todo)
let goalColorView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 3, height: cellHeight))
cell.contentView.addSubview(goalColorView)
goalColorView.backgroundColor = todo.area.uiColor()
```

and just changed it to

```
cell.addSubview(goalColorView)
```

and now it works perfect.

Not sure why.. looks like contentView is just little bit tricky.

Thanks for all your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Use auto-layout. Add constraints to icon and labels just.

Comment: thanks for suggestion Ankur! should I use auto-layout for non-custom UITableViewCell? for me it looks like it already has all required constraints margins etc for existing controls. Is there any known problem with UITableViewCell? Thanks.